# In C, calling a function from main

Tags: c, function

In C, I tried to call a function printSum from main. But the main function isn't calling printSum, its just printing out "Hi!" which is a print statement from main. I am not sure why printSum is not being called. Thanks.

Code:

```
int main(void){

  void printSum(void);
  printf("Hi!\n");

  return 0;
}

void printSum (void){
  printf("Please give two integers\n");
    int x,y;
  scanf("%d %d", &x,&y);
  printf("%d + %d is %d\n",x,y,x+y);
}
```

Sam

Comment: replac `void printSum(void)` with `printSum()` Also, define it before `main()`

Comment: have you attached a debugger and stepped through the code to figure out what happens when you step into pringSum?

Comment: CLearner learner = WhiteBook.getRitchieAwesomeness(); and your problems with C will be done...

Comment: Can someone recommend me a good beginners C book? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you defined it again..
Just remove the void from the funciton.
include a header a forward declartion so it will recognize it..

```
void printSum (void); <-------------------

int main(void){

  printSum();         <-------------------------
  printf("Hi!\n");

  return 0;
}

void printSum (void)
{
  printf("Please give two integers\n");
  int x,y;
  scanf("%d %d", &x,&y);
  printf("%d + %d is %d\n",x,y,x+y);
}
```

Comment: It was a declaration, not a definition.

Comment: I tried to edit this to fix the fact that you put "void" as an argument to the call...that won't compile.  But SO has this silly rule that edits have to be six characters ?!?.  Please delete thos four characters to make it correct.

Comment: sorry what exactly do you mean Lee Daniel?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're just starting out with C. Hopefully you have some experience with other languages, as C has a steep learning curve. Anyway, it's important to note a few things about C. The first is what `void printSum(void);` really means. Breaking it down:

**void** printSum(void);

This declares a return signature. In other words, what the function gives back to you. In C, the word `void` basically means "no variable". Remember that specifically. Why? Because C has another similar word, `NULL`. `NULL` means "no value." This is another way to look at it.

Some valid variables: `int`, `float`, `bool`, `void`
Some valid values: `1`, `'c'`, `2.0f`, `NULL`

In reality, `NULL` is actually just the number `0`. Literally. *`NULL == 0`* will return true.

Moving on...

void **printSum**(void);

This defines the name of the item.

void printSum **(** void **)**;

The parentheses mean this is a function.

void printSum(**void**);

This represents a variable being passed into the system. So this *could* have been int, float, etc.

void printSum(void) **;**

The semi-colon represents the end of a statement. This is a bit trickier of a concept to explain, but just think of it as finishing a sentence.

Now, the important bit here is the very first `void`. If you tell C what kind of thing a function returns, it assumes you are talking about the function, not actually calling it. Omitting the first void makes C attempt to *run* the function instead of *define* or *declare* it.

The difference between defining a function and declaring it is interesting and might be best saved for when you're a bit more accustomed to C.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't call `printSum`, it just declares it.  Change this line:

```
void printSum(void);
```

to

```
printSum();
```

If your functions are in the same order in your source file as you put them here, you'll also need to forward declare or move the implementation of `printSum` above `main` to be correct.

You should probably look into getting a beginner C book.

Comment: You can't just change the line; the declaration is necessary since the function is defined after main().  You need both.

Comment: I actually am learning form a C book...maybe its not exactly for beginners, its called "An introduction to Computer Science Using C" by John Carter.

Comment: Did you read it and see how function calls are made in one of its examples?

Comment: well he has a paragraph about the declaration of a function...thought I understood it but then in an example when he had declared it I didn't understand it and only understood it when people here explained it

Answer (score 2):

```
void printSum(void);
```

Does not actually call the function, it merely declares that it exists.  You need to do that so the compiler will know how to call it even though it hasn't been defined yet, so leave that line in.  But to actually call the function, you need:

```
printSum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because instead of actually calling the function, you are just declaring it.  To call the function you just need the function name and parameter list, which in this case is empty:

```
printSum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:-

```
void printSum(void);
```

is not a function call. It is a function declaration.

```
printSum();
```

is a function call. You should also forward declare the function before main.

Comment: and you also have to forward declare it.

Comment: Good point. Will edit answer

Comment: seems like you vote one down everyone's answers?? why dude?

Comment: I down voted the ones that were wrong. Isn't that what down votes are for?

Comment: Also, I might be rusty on straight C, but does C actually require forward declarations? I don't think it does. The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: ya dude, this has nothing to do with C or C++...it's the complier doesn't know of things that have yet to be defined.. :) hence have a function prototype then declare the function..

Comment: K&R C didn't require forward declarations. That is what I was thinking of. If it got something that looked like a function call, it just assumed it was a function returning int. Since C really only cares about the return type at the call site anyway, this was fine. Anyway, I digress. I made the update.